# "A dengue, a cólera e quatrocentas gramas" - O uso popular consagra?

Tags: gênero, uso-mais-comum

Há muitos anos, quando ainda não existia **"a dengue"** no Brasil, e muito menos **"a cólera"**, aprendi na faculdade de medicina que as doenças "dengue" e "cólera" são substantivos masculinos: "o dengue se alastra", "o amor nos tempos do cólera".  Que **"grama"**, a unidade de peso, é do gênero masculino, aprendi no curso secundário.  O meu Aurélio, 2ª edição, Editora Nova Fronteira, corrobora o que aprendi.  Contudo, tenho que admitir que em 2016 a maioria dos Brasileiros, incluindo a mídia, usa as três palavras como se fossem do gênero feminino.  A minha pergunta então é: **é aceitável dizer "trezentas gramas de farinha", "a dengue atingiu 25000 pessoas neste verão", "parece que a cólera deu uma trégua...".   Ou melhor, nos casos acima, o uso popular consagra como correto?**

Comment: De acordo com os dicionários que consultei, *dengue* é substantivo feminino, e *cólera* pode ser feminino ou masculino, então não aparece que são casos de "uso popular".

Comment: Oops, já achei um dicionário que diz que *dengue* é masculino. Interessante. O Priberam e o Michaelis dizem feminino, e o Infopedia masculino.

Comment: @DanGetz  Meu Aurélio é de 1994.  É provável que os dicionários que tu consultaste já tenham aderido ao "uso popular".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Cólera

Sempre ouvi como feminino; o [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/c%C3%B3lera) marca-o como feminino, o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/c%C3%B3lera) como dois géneros. Uma pesquisa no [CETEMPúblico](http://www.linguateca.pt/cetempublico/) mostra esta palavra invarialmente usada como nome feminino. A gramática de Bechara dá uma explicação para o uso como masculino, que se deve a ser um nome composto formado irregularmente:

> Os compostos são uma espécie de construção
>   sintática abreviada, de modo que, se são constituídos por substantivos
>   variáveis (biformes), o determinante (a 2.ª unidade) concorda
>   com o gênero do determinado e é responsável pelo gênero do composto:
>   *a batata-rainha* e não *a batata-rei*, *a ponta-seca* (instrumento de corte)
>
> [...]
>
> Contrariamente ao gênero da língua e por imitação inglesa, passou-se
>   a usar de compostos em que o determinante, invariável, ocupa o
>   primeiro lugar, e o determinado o segundo, ficando o gênero do composto
>   regulado por este último elemento: *a ferrovia*, *a aeromoça*.
>
> Segundo Martinz de Aguiar, por esta porta é que nos chegou o masculino
>   de *o cólera-morbo* (*morbo*, latino, é masculino) e, na forma reduzida, *o cólera*, e não por influência francesa. A passagem ao hoje mais usual e aceito *a cólera-morbo*, *a cólera*, se deveu à analogia com o processo regular no português.

O vocabulário oficial marca quer *cólera*, quer *cólera-morbo* como feminino. Parece-me que é seguro dizer que a forma feminina foi a que vingou.

### Dengue

Tenho ideia de ouvir *dengue* mais como nome masculino. O CETEMPúblico tem apenas uma entrada onde se pode discernir o género, e é masculino. Uma pesquisa no Google em jornais portugueses mostra que o uso oscila entre masculino e o feminino sem nenhum padrão à vista.

O [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/dengue) e o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/dengue) marcam o nome como feminino, mas o [vocabulário oficial](http://voc.cplp.org/index.php?action=lemma&lemma=5943&highlight=dengue) marca-o como masculino.

Conclusão: as duas formas parecem coexistir. O que é curioso é nenhuma fonte que consultei marcar o nome como de dois géneros.

### Grama

Este é um caso em que há fortes razões estruturais para usar o masculino. Ninguém diz *uma kilograma*, e *uma miligrama* parece ser também infrequente (~10-20x menos frequente a julgar pelo número de resultados no Google), portanto porquê *uma grama*?

O [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/grama) marca-o como masculino, mas o [Aulete admite os dois géneros](http://www.aulete.com.br/grama). O vocabulário oficial lista lemas para os dois casos, o que é de esperar dado que *grama* também existe como nome feminino. Parece-me que, no mínimo por uma questão de consistência, a forma masculina é recomendável. Além disso, falantes cultos (pelo menos em Portugal) usam preferencialmente o masculino -- o CETEMPúblico só tem ocorrências no masculino.

Comment: Desculpe a minha ignorância, mas o que é o CETEMPúblico?

Comment: Presumo que "a cólera" da tua resposta refere-se à infecção causada pelo Vibrio cholerae.

Comment: Aqui no Brasil, quando surgiu a primeira grande epidemia de dengue na década de 90 do século passado, os meios de comunicação diziam "a dengue".  Os médicos tentavam corrigir: "está errado, é masculino, é o dengue".  Mas o povo nunca tinha ouvido falar na doença anteriormente e passou a usar o gênero usado pela televisão: a dengue.  E assim ficou.  Hoje em dia eu mesmo falo "a dengue" para não soar pedante, pois 99% dos brasileiros assim falam.

Comment: @Centaurus É um corpus de artigos dos anos 80/90 de um jornal de referência português. Adicionei um link. Em relação a _cólera_, refiro-me à doença, sim.

Comment: Em tempo, muita gente fala "uma miligrama" por aqui.  Principalmente quando se trata de medicamentos.  "Doutor, o senhor pode me dar uma receita de Rivotril de uma miligrama?"   Ouve-se muito.  Já uma quilograma eu nunca ouvi, porque quase ninguém usa essa palavra.  no dia-a-dia.  Na feira, no mercado, e no açougue, todos dizem "um quilo".

Comment: @Centaurus Sim, talvez tenha sido demasiado taxativo. Editei a resposta.

Comment: *Programa* e *telegrama* são também masculinos, e aí ninguém se engana. Mas a ligação ao *grama* é só fonética e etimológica.

Comment: Artefacto, até que ponto o uso popular consagra e o errado passa a ser certo ?